# Permisos de carpetas incorrectos al subir archivos con Laravel en servidor centos7

Tags: cpanel, centos7, laravel-9

Estoy presentando el siguiente problema en mi VPS con WHM y CPANEL.
Tengo desplegado un proyecto con laravel 9 funciona todo parcialmente bien el problema es al subir los archivos y crear carpetas, pues estas carpetas creadas en el storage/app/public/NOMBRECARPETA. Quedan con permisos 700 y no 755, me toca estar cambiándolas manualmente a 755, hay alguna forma de poder corregir esto y que las carpetas nuevas queden con los permisos adecuados.
Nota el proveedor del VPS es Hosgator y cuento con WHM y CPANEL para poder crear los usuarios.
De antemano muchas gracias por la atención prestada.

Comment: ¿Con qué usuario les asignas dichos permisos? ¿Has intentado comunicarte con el proveedor (Hostgator)?